# Set max value of an input box based on another input box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I set the max value of amount input box based on balance input box? For example, if the value of balance input box is 500 so the max value of amount input box is 500. So when the user enters a number in amount input box greater than the value of balance input box, it will show an error message. How can I do that? I'm using angularjs to validate but it seems it's not working on my code.

This what I did: https://jsfiddle.net/mbnxdvpw/

This is how I retrieve the balance data. When the user clicks the payment icon it will show a modal and when it is success the balance data from the database will be retrieved in balance input.

```
function view_payment(payment_sales_id) {
    var modal = $('#payment-sales-modal');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        url: url + 'GetPaymentDetailsById', 
        data: { payment_sales_id : payment_sales_id }, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            modal.modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});
            modal.find($('#payment_sales_id')).val(payment_sales_id);
            modal.find($('#payment_net_amount')).val(data.sales_net_amount);
            modal.find($('#payment_balance')).val(data.sales_balance);
        }
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Balance <small>*</small></label>
    <input type="text" id="payment_balance" name="payment_balance" placeholder="Balance" class="form-control" ng-model="payment_balance" readonly>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Amount <small>*</small></label>
    <input type="text" id="payment_amount" name="payment_amount" placeholder="Amount" class="form-control" ng-model="payment_amount" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*$/" max="payment_balance.value">
    <span ng-messages="formPayment.payment_amount.$error" ng-if="formPayment.payment_amount.$dirty">
        <strong ng-message="pattern" class="text-danger">Please type numbers only.</strong>
        <strong ng-message="max" class="text-danger">Please enter a value less than or equal according to balance.</strong>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Help me guys, please.

Comment: Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are injecting the value directly on the input `payment_balance`, that's not the most cleanest angular way to do it. You should use `$scope` (check my js example below) so you could change it on the fly without need to find the input over and over again (probably not a problem on this particullary code, but one thing to have in mind).

Second, you should use a `<form>` to check for properties like `$error` or `$dirty`. That being said, I did an small [example](http://jsfiddle.net/z19befp4/) (not focusing the retrieved data).

Happy coding =}

Comment: The value of payment balance is retrieved from the database. Will I remove the line scope for payment balance?

Comment: Yep, like I said, I did make just a small snippet with a static value. Maybe you should change this line `modal.find($('#payment_balance')).val(data.sales_balance);` for `$scope.payment.paymentBalance = data.sales_balance;`. You need to initiate the other `$scopes` there to `$scope.payment = {}; $scope.payment.paymentAmount = '';`. That's more an angular wya to do it. And they need to be inside the same controller where the form is

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped on your problem.

Comment: I think if I move the data.sales_balance inside the scope it will not retrieve the data. It will retrieve the data when the ajax is success.

Comment: If you change the code inside of success it will just update when success occurs

Comment: Do I need to add this line $scope.apply(); at the end?

Comment: No. It will be applied directly

Comment: I did what you said but I got this error: $scope is not defined

Comment: Is there a change to fix that error? Thanks!

Comment: Help me please @JPeter

Comment: Well you need to inject the $scope on the controller. Sorry but I can't do all the work for yourself.

Comment: Well, because I did helped you getting your messages being displayed? Helping with explanation...